# Default Back Buttons Action Needed on newly created Button and Doubts about carrying Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent

In My Application i have 3 Activities A,B,C
I can go from A-->B-->C while going like this i want to carry Data's from A to B and A's data and B's Data to C and Save the Data to DB From Activity C.

My Problems Are

--> I Created a Back Button in B, on Clicking that it will Go to Activity A. I'm doing that using

> Intent goReceive1 = new Intent(Receive2.this,Receive1.class);
>   startActivity(goReceive1);

But it's Clearing Previously entered Data's in Activity in A. And i want those Data's to be Present while Going Back.
How Can i Achieve This?...

--> One More Doubt i have is i'm carrying Data's From A to B by using Bundle but i'm not using those data's in B i need those Data's from A and B in C so that i can Save Whole Data's to DB from C.

Please Anybody Help Me to Solve This issue...
Thanks in Advance..

---

I'm able to go from B-->A using myActivity.onBackPressed(); and previous data's i'm able to see there...

But Before going Back from B---> A i entered some Data's in B. I again went from A-->B then Data's in B got Cleared i don't want to loose any data that i entered till i press Save Button  from Activity C.

Is there Any way to achieve that?...

Comment: you'd rather simply call finish (unless you need to save data from B ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling intent to go back to your previous activity is totally wrong. You shouldn't do this.

Instead, in the back button that you have created in your Activity B simply call this method,

```
onBackPressed();
```

This is the default method which gets executed when the dedicated back button is pressed in your device.

And also if you need to pass data through intent, there is no way you can by pass a Activity. You have to pass it to the next activity and then pass on to the next Activity. You can't directly pass from A to C.

But maybe you can use the Application class and save the data there from Activity A and retrieve it in Activity C.

**EDIT**

Extend a Application class and save all your data there and then use it in C. You have to learn how to use Application class. The main idea here is that the data stored in Application class are persistent through out your app's runtime. It will not get cleared. Or you can even go for Shared preference.

Comment: Yah..It's Working But while i click next From Activity A-->B then Data's in B got cleared i need whole data's nothing should got cleared until i press Save from Activity C...is there Any Solution For that??

Comment: I don't Know more about Application class and shared preference..k i'll try to do that...thanks for replying...

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the solution of your problem.

You don't want to loose any data and share all data within all activities. So best approach for that is to extend `Application` class and save all your data in **application** and you can access data that is in application in any activity and service of your app. So you can use it as a medium to communicate between activities.

to know more about application instance check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

here is a very good example this http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state